# AWS S3 pre-signed URL with enforced content-md5

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I'm trying to use S3´s pre-signed URLs with an enforced Content-MD5. Therefore I'm basically trying to follow the example of their [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html). Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the checksum of the file I try to upload:

```
➜ md5 testfile.txt
MD5 (testfile.txt) = ce0a4a83c88c2e7562968f03076ae62f
```

Here is the code:

```
func main() {

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("eu-central-1")},
    )

    svc := s3.New(sess)

    resp, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(&s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("bucket"),
        Key:    aws.String("testfile.txt"),
    })

    md5 := "ce0a4a83c88c2e7562968f03076ae62f" // hard coded & pasted from "$ md5 testfile.txt"
    md5s := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(md5))

    resp.HTTPRequest.Header.Set("Content-MD5", md5s)

    url, err := resp.Presign(15 * time.Minute)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error presigning request", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("curl -XPUT -H \"Content-MD5: %s\" %s --upload-file %s\n\n", md5s, url, "testfile.txt")
}
```

Which *should* give me a ready-to-use curl command like: `curl -XPUT -H "Content-MD5: Y2UwYTRhODNjODhjMmU3NTYyOTY4ZjAzMDc2YWU2MmY=" https://bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/testfile.txt<super-long-url> --upload-file testfile.txt`

Unfortunately the request always fails with this message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidDigest</Code><Message>The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid.</Message><Content-MD5>Y2UwYTRhODNjODhjMmU3NTYyOTY4ZjAzMDc2YWU2MmY=</Content-MD5><RequestId>24F73D8948824799</RequestId><HostId>uKgSjxi03P4EvBk+Yo/EzxqWT0AI6AN3FPB2bKKAtgVjp8t4q2Ku+Tvui108vIQgcwgfvQdwmrk=</HostId></Error>
```

As I was a bit unsure whether I should request with the base64 of the MD5 I tried it with the normal MD5 as well which responses with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId><accesskeyid></AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20180127T215418Z
20180127/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request
e9580e510332d2fe8811209a8952e849022a56b93a02eca037fa43a10dec680f</StringToSign><SignatureProvided><signature></SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 31 38 30 31 32 37 54 32 31 35 34 31 38 5a 0a 32 30 31 38 30 [...]
</StringToSignBytes><CanonicalRequest>PUT
/testfile.txt
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&amp;X-Amz-Credential=<accesskeyid>%2F20180127%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20180127T215418Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=900&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-md5%3Bhost
content-md5:ce0a4a83c88c2e7562968f03076ae62f
host:bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com

content-md5;host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest><CanonicalRequestBytes>50 55 54 0a 2f 74 65 73 74 66 69 6c 65 2e 74 78 74 0a 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 41 6c 67 6f 72 69 74 68 6d 3d 41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 [...]
] 44</CanonicalRequestBytes><RequestId>D92C97EE37BE602A</RequestId><HostId>VatR9cidZlUgq+Ngd5vkZ+wHNiumsCPhx/TvZnwImAkj/STZ0eXazVrwGPRdketBbICd91VLG9E=</HostId></Error>
```

An upload works as soon as I remove the header setting`resp.HTTPRequest.Header.Set("Content-MD5", md5s)` and request with `curl -XPUT https://bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/testfile.txt<super-long-url> --upload-file testfile.txt`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because of the way base64 encoding works, the base64 representation of an md5 will always be exactly 24 characters long and the last 2 characters will always be `==`.  As you see, yours is about twice as long as it should be.

An actual md5 digest/hash is only 16 bytes (128 bits) long, and is a non-printable binary blob.

The `md5sum` utility and similar tools return the digest in a hex-encoded, printable format, which is 32 bytes long, consisting of only the characters 0-9 and a-f... it's the same value, but it's already been passed through hex-encoding, so that isn't the representation that you need to start with, if you want to base64-encode the md5 as required in the `Content-MD5` header.

`openssl dgst -md5 -binary {filename}` will generate the binary representation of the md5 of the file, or you can use a pipe to actually generate the final base-64 representation with `openssl dgst -md5 -binary {filename} | base64`.

Note that this has nothing to do with ssl of course, but I used the `openssl dgst` tool for this example because it's probably something you already happen to have on your system, as well as the `base64` conversion tool, which is probably already there, too.

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks! It was clear that the error is in the generation of the md5. This explains it very well. Thanks!